# HTMLCollection confusion

Tags: javascript, dom

If I call `document.getElementsByClassName('cl')`, I get a HTMLCollection. It seems to contain Element objects instead of HTMLElement objects, see [Flow source](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/b568c79543d9ed162b83c1405181958fb8809f85/lib/dom.js), or [Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) citing that it contains elements which are not HTMLElements. The [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#htmlcollection) writes that HTMLCollection is a historical artifact, although I cannot seem to find any suggested alternative (what is 'Elements'?).

So should I check if returned object is indeed a HTMLElement? What else could it be and when? Or is there a better way to do what `getElementsByClassName` and similar methods do? (without using external libraries)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: XML elements would be my guess.  Not everything is html anymore, so the removal of the name made sense at some point.

Comment: Yes I know that, but still, a HTMLDocument can only contain HTMLElements.

Comment: But in practice what those are and what they are implemented as might be subclasses of something else more generic and reusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM is not HTML exclusive. XML and SVG (which is a form of XML) are also supported by the DOM specifications. Element is a general object that maps to a single element of any type.

Also, the alternative is a [NodeList](https://devdocs.io/dom/nodelist) which is returned by `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Great, ```querySelector()``` ```and querySelectorAll()``` were what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: The querySelector functions requite a valid selector string so keep in mind the argument is different than the more specific getElement functions